# Tamper monkey post to another api

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I'm trying to get my script to take data from a webpage and then post it to my web server running on my local machine. (i'm **Scraping** a site and want to log the data locally). Below is my post however I'm getting the following error. I don't have access to the server/site source code that I need the data from.

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "http://localhost:3005/v1/myapi/add";
    xhr.open("POST", url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    var data = JSON.stringify({"serverIP": "10.10.10.10","totalConnections": totalConnections,"time": now});
    xhr.send(data);
```

Error:

> Refused to connect to 'http://localhost:3005/v1/myapi/add' because it
> violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src
> 'self'  'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'connect-src' was
> not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to setup CORS headers properly on the local server. Browsers do not allow sending POST requests from webpages to any host - it could be abused for spam etc.

Comment: Is there anyway around this?

Comment: You may check if GM has some alternative function that dodges CORS, but other than that, no. If therer was way around that, hackers could attack any website once they get a code snippet on some random website with lot of viewers.